# Proper role to non-interactive labels

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria

What's the proper role of non-interactive labels with tabindex=-1 on the project based on ARIA criteria? I search for something like role="label" but that doesn't seem to exist.

Most of the cases that I'm facing are related to labels without a huge function, it's just a little disclosure/guide to the user.

For instance: A label under a heading explaining some rule or identifying some field.

Comment: Could you share an example with code? Your first sound like you should group the heading with a paragraph into ’<hgroup>’, but the second sounds dangerous. Identifying inputs is a real ’<label>’ only valid use case, and pretty bad if missing.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the text is to identify a field, it should be a regular label `<label>`, or be referenced from the field with aria-labelledby attribute.
By identification, one usually mean a short name telling what the field is for. For example: username, password, e-mail, first name, delivery address, etc.

As a reminder, every field **must have a label** allowing screen readers to identify the field.
It's **mandatory**, and must preferably be short.

If the purpose of the field is rather to explain some rules, or if it's more lengthy expanations about what the field is for, it's better to reference that text with aria-describedby rather than aria-labelledby.
Example: "Password must contain at least one digit", or "Enter here the street and house number you want your order to be delivered to".

As a reminder, a description don't replace a label. It's a complement to it.
For example if you have a description saying "Enter here the street and house number you want your order to be delivered to", it isn't at all an excuse to omit an identification label "delivery address".
The label is always mandatory, while the description is completely optional.

Finally, if the purpose of the text is to give an example input or a format, ideally you should use the placeholder attribute instead of aria-describedby.
Example for an e-mail field: "john.doe@gmail.com", or for a date field: "yyyy-mm-dd".
A placeholder is also totally optional.

Now for the role of such texts, in fact there are no specific one. It's just text, a specific role isn't needed. As long as the field references the element with aria-labelledby or aria-describedby depending on the case explained above, it will work. Screen readers will give the specified information to the user at the right moment if it supports it.

A side note to conclude: probably that tabindex=-1 is totally useless for labels, descriptions or hints like that. There is no reason to focus them, even programmatically, since they don't provide interaction alone.
If needed, you will rather focus a given field instead, and when doing so, screen readers will read the identifying label as well.